# Android canvas draw multiple rectangles of equal distance

Tags: android, canvas, rect

I have 4 `Strings`. I'd like to draw a rectangle around each, and have them be equal distance to each other. I have code that "works" but I need 3 spaces for my last rectangle to make the distance equal, and I don't understand why. I am using an LG G Watch R, in case it is relevant.

```
private void drawDate(Canvas canvas, float centerX, float centerY)
    {
        float x = centerX + 75f;
        float y = centerY + 50f;
        String dayOfWeek = daysOfWeek[mTime.weekDay] + ",";
        String month = months[mTime.month];
        String monthDay = mTime.monthDay + ",";
        String year = Integer.toString(mTime.year);
        float height = outLinePaint.getTextSize();
        float totalWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(String.format("%s %s %s %s", dayOfWeek, month, monthDay, year));
        final float spaceWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(" ");
        x -= totalWidth/2f;
        outLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        float halfWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(dayOfWeek)/2f;
        canvas.drawRect(x - halfWidth, y - height, x + halfWidth, y + height /2f , whitePaint);
        canvas.drawText(dayOfWeek, x, y, outLinePaint);

        x += (halfWidth*2f)+spaceWidth;
        halfWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(month)/2f;
        canvas.drawRect(x - halfWidth, y - height, x + halfWidth, y + height /2f , whitePaint);
        canvas.drawText(month, x, y, outLinePaint);

        x += (halfWidth*2f)+spaceWidth;
        halfWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(monthDay)/2f;
        canvas.drawRect(x - halfWidth, y - height, x + halfWidth, y + height /2f , whitePaint);
        canvas.drawText(monthDay, x, y, outLinePaint);

        //THIS LINE
        x += (halfWidth*2f)+spaceWidth+spaceWidth+spaceWidth;
        //it looks right on the canvas, but why can I not simply
        //x += (halfWidth*2f)+spaceWidth; like above?
        halfWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(year)/2f;
        canvas.drawRect(x - halfWidth, y - height, x + halfWidth, y + height /2f , whitePaint);
        canvas.drawText(year, x, y, outLinePaint);

        outLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }
```

**NOTE: THIS "BUG" ONLY EFFECTS THE LAST STRING**

This is what I expect (AND what I get if I use `x += (halfWidth*2f)+spaceWidth+spaceWidth+spaceWidth;`):

[image: "Correct"]

However if I use `x += (halfWidth*2f)+spaceWidth;` like I do with my other 3, I get:

[image]

Comment: It might help if you posted an image of what you expect versus what you are getting now

Comment: @Karakuri, updated with pictures.

Comment: You make it too complex,  why do you use a center justification? Also all of this can be done easily using BackgroundColorSpan

Comment: @pskink, so it's centered in my rectangle, and the math seemed pretty easy. What do you suggest? Why doesn't it work for `year` but it does for the rest?

Comment: Use BackgroundColorSpan,  btw how is it centered if rect width == text width?

Comment: Also it doesn't work for the rest: try to replace "Sat," with "bla bla bla" and see the result

Comment: @pskink, Could you give me an example of what you'd suggest then? I've tried a couple of ways, and I feel I'm just being dumb now. I want all 4 to be centered on `x`, with equal distance in between.

Comment: How can you center on x if rect width == text width?

Comment: @pskink, maybe I'm not wording it correctly. I want the strings to appear as if I've called `canvas.drawText(String.format("%s %s %s %s", dayOfWeek, month, monthDay, year), x, y, paint);` with `paint`s textAlign to CENTER. But I need to draw them individually for the rectangle backgrounds.

Comment: Ok so "Sat," is centered horizontally?  If so, it is centered against what?

Comment: @pskink, It's centered against `x` so it doesn't draw to the left of `x`. Then `x` is incremented by the width of the last rectangle plus the width of a space for the next string. How would you accomplish what I have in the first screenshot?

Comment: Use a Spannable.setSpan with a BackgroundColorSpan, you will do that with 4 lines of code

Comment: @pskink, could you please give me a working example? The documentation on Spannable is horrendous.

Comment: @pskink, I'm not sure how I'd draw a `Spannable` either. This doesn't seem like a solution to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and show me if possible, because I am just not understanding.

Comment: `Canvas.drawText` will not draw the spans. If @MeetTitan can use a TextView, then spans will work and it will be much easier.

Comment: I suppose I could use a TextView, but I was trying to do it directly on the canvas like I do with all my other objects, as I've no Layouts in my project, and was trying to avoid adding one. Even if I do not and up using this approach, what is wrong with it? The logic seems solid to me. Perhaps this is worth a trip to CodeReview.

Comment: @Karakuri who said `Canvas.drawText`? Spannables are drawn with `android.text.Layout.draw()` method, see http://pastebin.com/5rwzCvRN

Comment: @MeetTitan ok i wrote a simple code, refer to http://pastebin.com/5rwzCvRN

Comment: @MeetTitan no need for CodeReview, i already suggested you what's wrong with your code (the comment with "bla bla bla") but i'm not gonna tell you the exact reason since you will use a bad approach in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I could not get @pskink's example to work for the life of me (it didn't draw on my canvas). The problem was my center alignment.

`x` was in the middle of my `Rect` not the left. Whereas I was expecting `x` to be the leftmost point in my `Rect` when I added its width to `x`.

I have fixed it by setting the text align to left (so that `x` IS my leftmost point), and changing my `drawDate()` method to:

```
float spaceWidth;
private void drawDate(float centerX, float centerY)
{
    float x = centerX + centerX*DATE_AND_COMPASS_X_OFFSET;
    float y = centerY + centerY*DATE_AND_COMPASS_Y_OFFSET;
    String dayOfWeek = daysOfWeek[mTime.weekDay] + ",";
    String month = months[mTime.month];
    String monthDay = mTime.monthDay + ",";
    String year = Integer.toString(mTime.year);
    float height = outLinePaint.getTextSize();
    float totalWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(String.format("%s %s %s %s", dayOfWeek, monthnthDay, year));
    spaceWidth = outLinePaint.measureText(" ");
    outLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    x-=totalWidth/2;
    x+=drawDateInline(dayOfWeek, x, y, height);
    x+=drawDateInline(month, x, y, height);
    x+=drawDateInline(monthDay, x, y, height);
    drawDateInline(year, x, y, height);
    outLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

private float drawDateInline(String word, float x, float y, float height) {
    float width = outLinePaint.measureText(word);
    canvas.drawRect(x, y - height, x + width, y + height /2f, whitePaint);
    canvas.drawText(word, x, y, outLinePaint);
    return width+spaceWidth;
}
```

I'm also not sure how this is a "bad approach".

Comment: The "bad approach" is the amount of your code, now compare it to my solution and the conclusion is obvious

Comment: @pskink, your "solution" did not work for me. The conclusion is very obvious to me. If you could provide me with a WORKING example that is shorter/more elegant, I'd be more than happy to up vote, accept, and use the answer.

Comment: if you had problems with integrating my snippet this is a COMPLETE class: http://pastebin.com/nKmhifvS with a explanation how to use it in Activity.onCreate method, i can post a screenshot showing the result if you want

Comment: @pskink, I am using a service (new android wear watch face API), thus there is no `setContentView()`, or `Context` for that matter. I also can't add a view to a `canvas` directly.

Comment: but you have some onDraw method, right? or something similar that has Canvas as a parameter, if so add `layout.draw(canvas)` there and it will just work, also i'm nowhere adding a View to a Canvas

Comment: ok, i took a look into CanvasWatchFaceService stuff and here you have a workinkg custom face: http://pastebin.com/z0QLgd8t